# How to animate unchanged ng-repeat with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I have a template that looks like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in myobj.items" class="toAnimate">{{item}}</p>
```

and I would like to use the animate module do a jQueryUI `addClass`/`removeClass` animation on the element using the JavaScript method described in the docs:

```
ngModule.animation('.toAnimate', function() {
  return {
    enter: function(element) {
      element.addClass('pulse').removeClass('pulse', 2000);
    }
  };
});
```

This works beautifully, but the problem is that, since I want to use the `p.toAnimate` element to display status messages, it will not change the content according to angular.

To break it down a little further, say I have a name field. When I click `Save` the message `Name was saved successfully.` is displayed. Now if I modify the name and click save again, assuming the save was successful, the message should be re-displayed to give the user feedback of the newly edited name. The pulse does not happen, however, because the items in myobj.items didn't technically change.

I realize that I could remove the item after a period of time (and that is probably the route I will take to implement the real solution), but I'm still interested to see if this sort of thing can be done using AngularJS.

What I want to do is register with angular that the message should be treated as new even though it is not. Is there any way to do this?

A fiddle to go along with this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jw3AT/

---

### UPDATE

There is a problem with the `$scope.$$phase` approach in my answer, so I'm still looking for the "right" way to do this. Basically, `$scope.$$phase` is always returning `$digest`, which causes the conditional to fail. Removing the conditional gives the correct result in the interface, but throws a [`$rootScope:inprog`](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24rootScope%3ainprog?p0=%24digest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I found is to add a `$apply` in the middle of the controller function:

```
$scope.updateThingy = function () {
    $scope.myobj.items = [];
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    $scope.myobj.items = ['Your name was updated.'];
};
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/744Rv/

May not be the best way, but it's an answer.

Comment: I would also suggest calling the apply as such to avoid the possibility of throwing already in process error.   if(!$scope.$$phase){$scope.$apply();}

Comment: Incorporated in answer. Reading up on it it seems kind of undocumented. Do you have any place where `$$phase` is detailed?

Comment: The $$phase if a flag the is either set to null or $digest depending on if angular is currently running a digest. I use this almost every time i want to insure that a digest is going to run (when getting data from outside the angular scope), however I had a few instances where it wont work and you must call the apply directly. It might also be the case that you need to call the the $apply on the $rootScope, but this is rare (only if you need to digest every watch in root and not just the local scope).